# many Shell Commands architecture

Tags: bash, docker, shell, makefile, gnu-make

at work, we are using docker and docker-compose, our developers need to start many containers locally and import a large database, there are many services that need to run together for development to be successful and easy.

so we sort of define reusable functions as `make` commands to make the code easier to maintain, is there another way to define and reuse many shell commands better than make.

for us due to network limitations running docker locally is the only option.

we managed to solve this challenge and make our developers' life easier by abstracting away complex shell commands behind multiple `make` targets, and in order to split these numerous `make` targets that control our docker infrastructure and containers we decided to split the targets among many files with `.mk` extension.

there are multiple `make` commands, like 40 of them, some of them are low level, some are meant to be called by developers to do certain tasks.

```
make launch_app
make import_db_script
make build_docker_images
```

but lately things are starting to become a little slow, with `make` commands calling other `make` commands internally, each `make` call is taking significant amount of time, since each lower level `make` call has to go through all defined `.mk` files, and do some calculations, as it shows when we run `make -d`, so it starts to add up to a considerable overhead.

is there any way to manage a set of complex shell commands using anything other than make, while still being easy for our developers to call.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to manage dependencies, you need make, or any of the similar build tools (bake, rake, ...). Consider providing more details about the makefile. Dependecy check is usually fast (timestamp) - may be the makefiels are forcing lot of unneeded execution. Repeating commands, instead of executing them once, etc.

Comment: When you're calling targets from other targets, are you invoking make again, or marking the target as a dependency? First approach could be very slow.

Comment: One tool you might consider is [earthly](https://github.com/earthly/earthly), which is a Makefile crossed with Docker. Haven't used it myself, so can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could always just write your shell commands in a shell script instead of a makefile.  Using shell functions, shell variables, etc. it can be managed.  You don't give examples of how complex your use of make constructs is.

StackOverflow is not really a place to ask open-ended questions like "what's the best XYZ".  So instead I'll treat this question as, "how can I speed up my makefiles".

To me it sounds like you just have poorly written makefiles.  Again, you don't show any examples but it sounds like your rules are invoking lots of sub-makes (e.g., your rule recipes run `$(MAKE)` etc.)  That means lots of processes invoked, lots of makefiles parsed, etc.  Why don't you just have a single instance of make and use prerequisites, instead of sub-makes, to run other targets?  You can still split the makefiles up into separate files then use `include ...` to gather them all into a single instance of make.

Also, if you don't need to rebuild the makefiles themselves you should be sure to disable the built-in rules that might try to do that.  In fact, if you are just using make to run docker stuff you can disable *all* the built-in rules and speed things up a good bit.  Just add this to your makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

(see [Options Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) for details of this option).

**ETA**

You don't say what version of GNU make you're using, or what operating system you're running on.  You don't show any examples of the recipes you're using so we can see how they are structured.

The problem is that your issue, "things are slow", is not actionable, or even defined.  As an example, the software I work on every day has 41 makefiles containing 22,500 lines (generated from cmake, which means they are not as efficient as they could be: they are generic makefiles and not using GNU make features).  The time it takes for my build to run when there is nothing to actually do (so, basically the entire time is taken by parsing the makefiles), is 0.35 seconds.

In your comments you suggest you have 10 makefiles and 50 variables... I can't imagine how any detectable slowness could be caused by this size of makefile.  I'm not surprised, given this information, that `-r` didn't make much difference.

So, there must be something about your particular makefiles which is causing the slowness: the slowness is not inherent in make.  Obviously we cannot just guess what that might be.  You will have to investigate this.

Use `time make launch_app`.  How long does that take?

Now use `time make -n launch_app`.  This will read all makefiles but not actually run any commands.  How long does that take?

If `make -n` takes no discernible time then the issue is not with make, but rather with the recipes you've written and switching to a different tool to run those same recipes won't help.

If `make -n` takes a noticeable amount of time then something in your makefiles is slow.  You should examine it for uses of `$(shell ...)` and possibly `$(wildcard ...)`; those are where the slowness will happen.  You can add `$(info ...)` statements around them to get output before and after they run: maybe they're running lots of times unexpectedly.

Without specific examples of things that are slow, there's nothing else we can do to help.

Comment: thank you very much, i don't know what the examples will do, i have many variables, maybe like 50, defined in a single .mk file, some of them use `=` but most use `:=`, and multiple files, close to 10, that contain the targets and use these variables, sometimes commands override these variables for submakes.

there's one MAKEFILE in the root of the project that includes all .mk files defined in another folder.

i tried your solution with benchmarks, there was no difference at all using this sadly.

Comment: i think you got this in the ETA, since each submake has to go through the whole set of files, it will have to execute all `$(shell ...)` calls we made, so that must be the reason, thank you for your help

Comment: As I mentioned in the first part of my answer, why do you use sub-makes?  Why not just use a single make program, and use prerequisites to run other rules?  That's how make is designed to work.  If you really can't avoid sub-makes you can pass the values of computed/expensive variables on the sub-make command line, like `$(MAKE) VAR1='$(VAR1)' VAR2='$(VAR2)'` etc.  This will override the value so the sub-make won't re-compute it.

Comment: i do a lot of overrides yes, if you flatten all make targets, the code will reach an unmaintainable state, making it impossible to work with.

Comment: you have like tens of variables you also cannot override all of them, some of them are overriden like when you override regular default function parameters in other languages.

Comment: I didn't say combine all the makefiles into a single makefile.  I said, run a single _make_ process.  keep all your current individual makefiles, but have one top-level one that includes all the others.  then instead of running sub-makes, use prerequisites to ensure ordering.  I don't see why a makefile rule like `do-thing: ; $(MAKE) other-thing; do-this-thing` is more readable than `do-thing: other-thing; do-this-thing`.

Comment: You don't have to override all the variables, only the ones that take a long time.  And I don't know what you mean by _some of them are overridden like when you override regular default function parameters_.  If you mean, you already override some of them on the make command line when you invoke `make`, that's fine: any values on the command line will continue to override values set in the makefile.  However, I do **not** recommend this method.  I'm just saying it's an option.  The right answer is to use my previous suggestion and write your rules to use dependencies instead of recursion.

Comment: Anyway, I don't have much else to add.  The cause of the slowness is not make, but rather the way you've written your makefiles.  If you want it to go faster, then you'll have to write them a different way which avoids running the same commands over and over.  If you want to provide us with some examples of your actual makefile rules, then we can show you how to rewrite them to avoid recursion.  If you just don't want to rewrite them, then you'll have to live with slowness I guess... any other tool will have the same slowness if you run the commands multiple times.